# javascript not working (if else )

Tags: javascript, html

I was following this [tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_intro_lightbulb)

and I tried to make my own one, but it's not working. This is my code:

the error console

uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
4emoji.html:32 Uncaught ReferenceError: run is not definedonclick @ emoji.html:324emoji.html:32 Uncaught ReferenceError: run is not definedonclick @ emoji.html:3210emoji.html:38 Uncaught ReferenceError: m2 is not definedonclick @ emoji.html:38

```
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="zh">

<
<img id="boy" onclick="run()" src="emoji\walk.png">
<br>running boy
<br>
<img id="moon" onclick="m()" src="emoji\1.png">
<br>moon

<script>
function run() {
var image = document.getElementById('boy');
if (image.src.match("emoji\walk")) {
    image.src = "emoji\run.png";
} else {
    image.src = "emoji\walk.png";
}
}
function m() {
var image = document.getElementById('moon');
if (image.src.match("emoji\1.png")) {
    image.src = "emoji\2.png";
} else {
if (image.src.match("emoji\2.png")) {
    image.src = "emoji\3.png";
} else {
if (image.src.match("emoji\3.png")) {
    image.src = "emoji\4.png";
} else {
if (image.src.match("emoji\4.png")) {
    image.src = "emoji\5.png";
} else {
if (image.src.match("emoji\5.png")) {
    image.src = "emoji\6.png";
} else {
if (image.src.match("emoji\6.png")) {
    image.src = "emoji\7.png";
} else {
if (image.src.match("emoji\7.png")) {
    image.src = "emoji\8.png";
} else {
image.src = "emoji\1.png";
}
}
</script>
```

I have confirmed the name of the img is correct

Comment: Define "doesn't work".  What *does* it do?  At the very least, this looks like a syntax error because you open a lot of curly braces that you never close.

Comment: *"but it do not work"* is not a proper technical problem statement and there is no mention of errors thrown in browser dev tools console here and that should always be your first place to look

Comment: i have checked that all the brances has close

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are trying to do this:

```js
function run() {
  var image = document.getElementById('boy');
  if (image.src.match("emoji\walk")) {
    image.src = "emoji\run.png";
  } else {
    image.src = "emoji\walk.png";
  }
}

function m() {
  var image = document.getElementById('moon');

  if (image.src.match("emoji\1.png")) {
    image.src = "emoji\2.png";
  } else if (image.src.match("emoji\2.png")) {
    image.src = "emoji\3.png";
  } else if (image.src.match("emoji\3.png")) {
    image.src = "emoji\4.png";
  } else if (image.src.match("emoji\4.png")) {
    image.src = "emoji\5.png";
  } else if (image.src.match("emoji\5.png")) {
    image.src = "emoji\6.png";
  } else if (image.src.match("emoji\6.png")) {
    image.src = "emoji\7.png";
  } else if (image.src.match("emoji\7.png")) {
    image.src = "emoji\8.png";
  } else {
    image.src = "emoji\1.png";
  }      
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="zh">

< <img id="boy" onclick="run()" src="emoji\walk.png">
  <br>running boy
  <br>
  <img id="moon" onclick="m()" src="emoji\1.png">
  <br>moon

  <script>
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would highly suggest going over programming fundamentals, you have two major issues here. First, you are nesting `if` statements inside `else` when you are looking for `else if`. You cannot have multiple `else`. The second issue, which is likely throwing the error, is that you are not closing the curly braces. Just do the math, you have about two open curly braces for every one you close. Please use this syntax:

```
if (condition) {
  // result
} else if (condition2) {
  // result2
} else {
 // result 3
}
```